# Ссылка на абзац на той же странице с Laravel

Tags: php, css, ajax, laravel, anchor

Вот у меня есть обычный div, который выводит катерии моей страницы, мне нужно чтобы при клике на категорию scrolling в определенную часть абзаца этой же страницы.

```
                  @php
                  $faq = \App\Services\AppService::getFaq();
                  @endphp

                   <div class="faq-left">
                     <p>{{__('Оглавление')}}</p>
                       @foreach($faq as $category => $items)
                         <span id="menu_scroll_tag" class="text-muted">
                           <ul>
                             <li><a href="#">{{$category}}</a></li>
                           </ul>
                        </span>
                     @endforeach
                  </div>
```

Категории выводятся уже с back-end, сделать типа

```
              <span id="menu_scroll_tag" class="text-muted">
                    <ul>
                        <a id="prod" href="#">Продукты</a>
                        <a id="prod" href="#">Одежда</a>
                        <a id="prod" href="#">Одежда</a>
                    </ul>
                </span>
```

мне не подходит, поскольку вывод уже производится с back-end. Как правильно сделать Ajax? Помогите разобраться. Спасибо

Мой controller

```
public static function getFaq(){
    return Faq::all()->groupBy('category');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если твои абзацы которые ты хочешь привязать к категориям тоже выводятся в цикле из бэкенда, то ты можешь при выводе привязать идентификатор к id абзаца или какому-нибудь data-id. Можешь сделать так чтобы эти же id были и у оглавления, и тогда на js повесить на каждое оглавление событие которое проскроллит страницу к блоку абзаца с таким же айди как и у оглавления. Если тебе надо подгружать аяксом динамично абзац по клику на оглавление (прости я не совсем до конца понял вопрос) то также по клику отправляешь на сервер id который привязан к каждому оглавлению. Так:

```
<li><a href="#" id="{{$category->id}}">{{$category}}</a></li>
```

И в js аяксом отправляешь на сервер данную информацию -

```
let id = item.attr('id');
```

Сервер получает это, возвращает абзац. Делаешь там append какой-нибудь с этой информацией и всё. С js-ом не смогу помочь, извини( вопрос по laravel